# key mismatch (only) using single sign-on

Tags: android, facebook

I put the Android key hash in the developer settings, like described here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sig

it works, using the app for months already.

Now I want to enable single sign-on.

Did the steps, described in the same page (in the Android app and enable single sign on in the developer account). But I get in the app:

invalid_key:Android key mismatch. Your key "
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

" does not match the allowed keys specified in your application settings. Check your application settings at http://www.facebook.com/developers

(I removed the key for SO).

What is the problem? Everything works if I don't use single sign on. Is the key maybe not used, when not using single sign on (don't believe that).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems that the key hash is necessary only for single sign-on. So mine is probably wrong, and it's ignored when not using single sign-on.

Edit: Confirmed, changing the key fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error once, and it is a result of using Single Sign On and not having the correct key hash on the facebook part of your app.

To fix this, and to be able to use single sign on, take the key that is in your error message and paste it in the Android key hash field.

This should fix your problem. The key hash is only used when you have enabled single sign on, which is why it gets ignored when you turn SSO off.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's what I also suggested in my answer. Was confused, because I thought that the key was used for everything.